# Definite integral

Tags: integration

I am struggling with the following integral
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\,\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\,(2-x)}\mathrm{d}x$$

Is it worth it trying to solve it in the complex plane?

Comment: there is little hope for a closed form expression, but of course you can just calculate it numerically to any desired accuracy; do you need more?

Comment: Just as a point of information: Mathematica seems unable to do this integral, and finds a numerical value of about 0.5516201240139423. Plugging this number into an online inverse symbolic calculator yields no "nice" result.